# Visual Studio 2012/13 on the same PC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Do I have to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 to try the 2013 Preview?
Can they both sit happily on the same PC?

Comment: All visual studio versions can live side-by-side.

Comment: If you care about an answer enough then don't install alpha versions of software on a machine that you need to get your job done.  This tends to be okay when you install it, not when you uninstall it.

Comment: @HansPassant: To support the point - I could not install 2013 Preview on top of my 2008, 2010 and 2012. It failed half way through. Ended up having one of the **other** versions corrupted and a lot of trouble with repairs thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

You can have them both on the same PC. I have VS 2010 and VS 2012 both installed on my machine

Comment: I have VS2010, 12 and 13 Preview :)